# How to remove an item from every dict in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Sample:

```
sample = {
    "value1": "foo",
    "value2": "bar",
    "value3": "baz",
    "array": [
        {
            "key1":'value1',
            "key2":'value2',
            "key3":'value3',
        },
        {
            "key1":'value4',
            "key2":'value5',
            "key3":'value6',
        },
        {
            "key1":'value7',
            "key2":'value8',
            "key3":'value9',
        }
          ]
}
```

I need to delete all key1s and values from all dicts in this array leaving only key2, key3 in each object.

The only thing I can find from google is how to iterate and delete an entire dict in an list, not a single key.

Haven't tried deleting but I did just try to get the other values like this.. couldn't get this either

```
    domains_list = dict(map(lambda item: (item['key1'], item['key2']), sample['array'].items()))
```

> error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: `for inner_dict in sample['array']: delete inner_dict['key1']`? Is there any reason to make it more complicated?

Comment: What are `value1, value2, value3`? That's not allowed in a dictionary.

Comment: I am new to python and JS is a little harder than that so I do make it too complicated. It worked, thanks! MatsLindh

Comment: Please **always** provide a [mcve]. The code you've posted *wont' even compile*.  Please don't be lazy, help us help you

Comment: Will do, I thought it would be easy for an experienced dev, so I was lazy. Wont do again!

Comment: @MatsLindh so, you need `del inner_dict["key1"]`, but in JS, the equivalent would be `for (obj of sample['array']){ delete obj.key1};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get You moving: `sample['array']` is a list (python type), which doesnt have `.items()`. So I'd iterate something like `for dictionary in sample['array']` and then call `dictionary.items()`.